# Can I stop Angular binding failing silently?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following table markup:

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clientsIndex">
    <td>{{client.fullName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.contactPhone}}</td>
</tr>
```

When the view for this renders, I see only one column is populated, but nothing logged in the console. Is there a way I can tell angular this is a debugging session, and I'd like to see big screaming error messages if I make a copy and paste mistake?

Comment: no , it fails silently by design. There is no way for angular to know that the object won't be set later to have a `debug` that would be useful

Comment: @charlietfl Surely at the time the {{}} expression is evaluated whatever does that can output a non-blank value at least? Or is the binding expression compiled into the module and not evaluated at 'runtime'?

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular but perhaps you could set some dummy values before you set the actual values to see where you are going wrong?

Comment: should'nt it {{client.contactPhone}}?

Comment: @Nagasimha that's intentional, and what you just wrote is basically what he wants pointed out to him automatically by the system :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Surely at the time the {{}} expression is evaluated whatever does that can output a non-blank value at least?

As of Angular 1.1.5 there is support for ternary operators in templates. So you can define something like this to get a default value if undefined:

```
<tr ng-repeat="client in clientsIndex">
    <td>{{client.fullName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.contactPhone ? item.contactPhone : 'Error: not defined'}}</td>
</tr>
```

The general structure is: `{{(condition) ? (expression if true) : (expression if false)}}`.

Comment: Thank you. I had just successfully used the ternary operator on Friday for the first time, and it just never occurred to me I could use it here.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purpose you can select the element using any angular.element("") selectors and see the scope of that element to check the variable you are trying to access inside the element is inside the scope available to that element.Find the example below.i have used an id selector you can use a child selector.

```
<tr id="canbeReplacedWithChildSelectors" ng-repeat="client in clientsIndex">
<td>{{client.fullName}}</td>
<td>{{item.contactPhone}}</td>
</tr>
```

**angular.element("#canbeReplacedWithChildSelectors").scope()** execute this and check `client.fullName` is available in the scope.in your case angular.element("#canbeReplacedWithChildSelectors").scope().client would give you undefined.